# Should I re-wax downhill skis after using skins?

Tags: skiing, snow, cross-country-skiing

I was skinning into a yurt last weekend with my regular downhill ([telemark](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/what-is-the-benefit-to-telemark-skiing)) skis. On the way back out, I noticed a lot more snow sticking to my skis... Granted, the weather was hot, and snow was sticky - but it made me wonder:

Does the stickum on skins either remove the glide wax or leave a sticky residue I should be concerned about? And if so, how do I remove/mitigate?

Answer (score 6):

Having snow stick to the bottom of touring or telemark skis after removing skins is a common occurrence.  You can mitigate it by bringing some glide wax with your or by using a liquid or spray. I keep a little a glide wax that looks like underarm deodorant in the bottom of my avy pack just for this purpose.

Comment: Interesting... So are the skins removing the wax on the base, or is it leaving stickum behind? I assume the former based on your answer.

Comment: @LBell the skins leave sticky adhesive behind.